# YouTube V3 api returns considerably different LIKEs and Comments results from numbers on the Web

Tags: youtube-data-api

YouTube v3 api returns significantly different LIKEs count from what is on the web version of YouTube.

Compare these:
https://monosnap.com/file/EdtDNTTGDK06zoCZ7IXkMdzn6WuyOo
https://monosnap.com/file/CcJOiKl9CBMyncHQSrPv3lkLOuqeDD

To replicate:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=jWnhFM1Ttwg&key={api_key}&maxResults=50&part=statistics (https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials - use your Youtube V3 key)

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have any documentation *(from the YouTube Data API v3)* that backs me up for what I going to say, I'll drop some thoughts about why the API returns different values in the "`likeCount`" section comparing to the YouTube actual video *(saw in the main website)*:

---

I think that the differences in the results returned by the API and the results shown in the website are due to:

- YouTube has its own calculations for set the values in the website, the API results and in the YouTube Analytics<sup>1</sup>.
- It would be possible that those additional "likes" retrieved in the API aren't exposed to the calculations made by YouTube.

---

<sup>1</sup> Extracted from [this answer in the Google Support webpage](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1715144?hl=en):

> - **The number of likes/dislikes in YouTube Analytics may be different than what you see on the watch page under the video**. This
>     is a known issue and our team is working to fix this. In the meantime,
>     **please refer to the counts on the watch page under the video for the most accurate count**.

And

> - In rare instances, you might see more likes/dislikes than views since **these metrics are adjusted by different verification
>     systems**.

---

For the specific `videoId` you posted in your question, I did check at `2019-01-25` and the results were:

- likeCount "*by the API*": 1341
- likeCount "*in the YouTube website*": 851

Check again at `2019-01-28` the numbers did changed:

- likeCount "*by the API*": 1367
- likeCount "*in the YouTube website*": 877

You can try [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22statistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22jWnhFM1Ttwg%22%7D#try-it) the API request for get these results - *(results for current day)*.

If you make a substract from the `likeCount` values gotten above, you'll get `26`.

Maybe it is futile try make any mathematical operation for set the "correct" value shown in the YouTube website *(using the `likeCount` result from the YouTube Data API)*, but if anyone want give it a try, I encourage you to share your answer.