# youtube api shows wrong like count

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a weird bug with the youtube api v3.

When I request the api (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=JvW_xMUaxOU&key=123&part=statistics) I get the following response:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/vVazVk2gJI2cdevvGp3gvGvmTyY\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/8xDm4iqCrNo781FKu8VtuLwv7XU\"",
   "id": "JvW_xMUaxOU",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "3352",
    "likeCount": "805",
    "dislikeCount": "69",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "5"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But when I look at the likes through the video, the like count is 314. When I press like, it goes up, after a feew seconds.

One other weird, but interesting thing is, that the view count and dislike count is correct.

Is there a bug or something else? Other videos are shown correct.

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54407644/4092887) about the reasons I think are the cause of this situation.